# C++ std::condition_variable in class context

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to manage prioritized resource access of a camera in an embedded system. Therefore I made a camera interface which uses a std::condition_variable to realize this.

```
typedef std::function<void()> UnlockCameraHandler;

class Camera {
    const int MAX_PRIORITY = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int currentPriority = MAX_PRIORITY;
    bool mLockable = true;
    UnlockCameraHandler mUnlockCameraHandler;
    std::condition_variable_any cameraLock;
    std::mutex cameraMut;

public:
    bool isLockable(int priority) {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mLock(cameraMut);
      if (priority < currentPriority) {
        mLock.unlock();
        return true;
      } else {
        mLock.unlock();
        return false;
      }
    }

    void unlock() {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mLock(cameraMut);
      if (mLockable) {
        return;
      }
      currentPriority = MAX_PRIORITY;
      mLockable = true;
      cameraLock.notify_all();
      mLock.unlock();
    }

    bool lock(int priority, UnlockCameraHandler handler) {
      if (priority < 0) {
        return false;
      }
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mLock(cameraMut);
      if (priority < currentPriority) {
        if (mUnlockCameraHandler) {
          mUnlockCameraHandler();
        }
      }
      if (!mLockable) {
        cameraLock.wait(mLock, std::bind(&Camera::isLockable, this, priority));
      }
      mUnlockCameraHandler = handler;
      currentPriority = priority;
      mLockable = false;
      mLock.unlock();
      return true;
    }
};
```

I wrote some Catch2 Unit-Tests for these functions to also ensure that it works with more than one thread.

```
struct CameraLock {
  std::shared_ptr<TestCamera> camera;

  void unlock_handler() { camera->unlock(); }
};

TEST_CASE_METHOD(CameraLock, "Camera lock mechanism") {

  SECTION("lock and unlock camera") {
    camera->lock(100, std::bind(&CameraLock::unlock_handler, this));
    REQUIRE(!camera->isLockable(100));
    camera->unlock();
    REQUIRE(camera->isLockable(100));
  }

  SECTION("lock with higher priority") {
    std::thread low{[&]() {
      REQUIRE(camera->lock(100, std::bind(&CameraLock::unlock_handler, this)));
    }};
    std::thread high{[&]() {
      REQUIRE(camera->lock(50, std::bind(&CameraLock::unlock_handler, this)));
    }};
    low.join();
    high.join();
  }

  SECTION("lock with lower priority") {
    std::thread high{[&]() {
      REQUIRE(camera->lock(50, std::bind(&CameraLock::unlock_handler, this)));
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
      camera->unlock();
    }};

    std::thread low{[&]() {
      REQUIRE(camera->lock(100, std::bind(&CameraLock::unlock_handler, this)));
      camera->unlock();
    }};
    high.join();
    low.join();
    REQUIRE(camera->isLockable(100));
  }

  SECTION("lock with 3 parties") {
    std::thread high{[&]() {
      REQUIRE(camera->lock(50, std::bind(&CameraLock::unlock_handler, this)));
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
      camera->unlock();
    }};

    std::thread low{[&]() {
      REQUIRE(camera->lock(100, std::bind(&CameraLock::unlock_handler, this)));
      camera->unlock();
    }};

    std::thread mid{[&]() {
      REQUIRE(camera->lock(75, std::bind(&CameraLock::unlock_handler, this)));
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
      camera->unlock();
    }};
    high.join();
    low.join();
    mid.join();
    REQUIRE(camera->isLockable(100));
  }
}
```

It should work in that way that when a process wants to access the camera resource, it calls lock() to reserve it, passing a priority value and a Callback function. The Callback function serves the purpose that if another process wants to access the camera with a higher priority, the process that currently has the access does the appropriate work to free the resource and calls unlock() afterwards, so that the prioritized process can lock it.
If a process with a lower priority wants to access the resource, it calls the wait() function of the condition_variable and blocks until the prioritized process calls unlock().

The Unit-Tests do pass most of the time, but sometimes I'm getting a segmentation fault or a double free() error (especially in the "lock with 3 parties" section) which tells me that my implementation isn't thread safe.

Here's a minimal example of the code to run for everyone who might want to debug it:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
 
typedef std::function<void()> UnlockCameraHandler;
 
class Camera {
    const int MAX_PRIORITY = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int currentPriority = MAX_PRIORITY;
    bool mLockable = true;
    UnlockCameraHandler mUnlockCameraHandler;
    std::condition_variable_any cameraLock;
    std::mutex cameraMut;
 
public:
    bool isLockable(int priority) {
      if (priority < currentPriority) {
        mLock.unlock();
        return true;
      } else {
        mLock.unlock();
        return false;
      }
    }
 
    void unlock() {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mLock(cameraMut);
      if (mLockable) {
        return;
      }
      currentPriority = MAX_PRIORITY;
      mLockable = true;
      cameraLock.notify_all();
      mLock.unlock();
    }
 
    bool lock(int priority, UnlockCameraHandler handler) {
      if (priority < 0) {
        return false;
      }
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mLock(cameraMut);
      if (priority < currentPriority) {
        if (mUnlockCameraHandler) {
          mUnlockCameraHandler();
        }
      }
      if (!mLockable) {
        cameraLock.wait(mLock, std::bind(&Camera::isLockable, this, priority));
      }
      mUnlockCameraHandler = handler;
      currentPriority = priority;
      mLockable = false;
      mLock.unlock();
      return true;
    }
};
 
std::shared_ptr<Camera> camera = std::make_shared<Camera>();
 
void unlock_handler() { camera->unlock(); }
 
int main() {
 
    std::thread high{[&]() {
      camera->lock(50, std::bind(&unlock_handler));
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
      camera->unlock();
    }};
 
    std::thread low{[&]() {
      camera->lock(100, std::bind(&unlock_handler));
      camera->unlock();
    }};
 
    std::thread mid{[&]() {
      camera->lock(75, std::bind(&unlock_handler));
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
      camera->unlock();
    }};
    
    high.join();
    low.join();
    mid.join();
}
```

May someone tell me what's wrong with my code and how to adjust it to meet my exceptations?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a note that you seem to have missed: "_`wait` causes the current thread to block until the condition variable is notified **or a spurious wakeup occurs**_"

Comment: @TedLyngmo Shouldn't that be accounted for by passing the `isLockable` function to `wait`?

Comment: why m_lockable and priority are not always part of protected by mutex code?

Comment: @Federico If I aquire the mutex in `unlock` before resetting the variables, the test cases sometimes freeze, probably waiting for another thread to unlock the mutex, which never occurs. Also I'm seeing the `double free or corruption (out)` error in this case, too.

Comment: `unlock` needs to lock `cameraMut` before modifying `currentPriority` and `mLockable`  or you'll have race conditions. `lock` also needs to lock `cameraMut` before testing `mLockable`

Comment: This seems like a good time to try a tool like ThreadSanitizer.

Comment: @MauriceDupont It could possibly help but check [this](https://godbolt.org/z/nefe1fova). Does that do what you expect it to do? You probably want to put `priority` in a `std::reference_wrapper` like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Pnv1bW8ca)

Comment: @TedLyngmo The links sadly don't work on my side.

Comment: @MauriceDupont Oh, ok. In short. I _think_ you want `cameraLock.wait(mLock, std::bind(&Camera::isLockable, this, std::ref(priority)));` instead. Otherwise `priority` will have a copy of the value it had when you called `std::bind` so that's what `isLockable` will receive - which seems meaningless.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I changed the code in the question, but the errors persist.

Comment: If you want more debugging help please provide a [mre]

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's helpful, but sadly it doesn't solve the original problem. I'm mostly getting the `double free or corruption (out)` error at this point.

Comment: I assume something initialises `CameraLock::camera`?

Comment: @MauriceDupont Yeah, I didn't imagine that was the single problem, but it _is_ a problem. Break it down into smaller problems and get familiar with how these things work. It's also simpler to create [mre]s if you are trying out one specific thing. When you dump a part of a much larger set of functions and classes, we can only point at potential problems - but we can't reproduce them. When people present reproducible problems, they tend to get solved pretty quickly.

Comment: @AlanBirtles It initialized automatically through Catch2. Otherwise the tests would never succeed in the first place.

Comment: I don't know how I should compress it further, but here is some minimized example. I couldn't get an error out of it until now though, but it's basically the same code.
https://pastebin.com/URcK1RJ0

Comment: If it doesn't reproduce the problem then it's not a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles The problem is that even the production code doesn't reproduce the problem consistently. Mostly it runs just fine.

Comment: ThreadSanitizer reports lots of data races.  Basic rule: Any time you access a variable shared between threads, whether reading or writing, you must hold an appropriate mutex.  Two exceptions: (1) if every thread is only reading and no thread ever writes that variable; (2) if the variable is `std::atomic`.  In your pastebin version, `unlock` reads `mLockable` without holding the mutex; and `lock` reads both `mLockable` and `currentPriority`, all of which are able to be written by other threads.  So let's get those fixed, and then see what bugs are left.

Comment: It could be that you want two mutexes here: one to guard the camera itself (held as long as the camera is in use by a thread), and another to guard the `mLockable` and `currentPriority` variables (held only briefly when those variables are updated or tested).  Once it works, you could consider further optimizations by making them atomic and replacing read-write pairs with the appropriate atomic RMW operation, but I suggest making it correct before worrying about making it fast.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful to put the pastebin version of your code into the question, so that people who aren't familiar with Catch2 can read and test your code.  It's normal that it's hard to reproduce bugs resulting from races, but there are tools to help with that.

Comment: @NateEldredge I edited the code in a way that I'm aquiring the mutex every time a shared variable gets accessed, but now it is resulting in a deadlock. From what I have observed, the last thread blocks in the `unlock` function while trying to aquire the mutex when it's still held by another thread, although all functions should have it unlocked as soon as they finish. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `lock` with higher priority _ever_ work? It looks like it will deadlock as soon as your test hits the `if (priority < currentPriority)` branch ...

Answer (score 0):

Your `unlock` method locks the mutex:

```
    void unlock() {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mLock(cameraMut);
      // ...
    }
```

and is called by your `lock` method with the mutex already held:

```
    bool lock(int priority, UnlockCameraHandler handler) {
      if (priority < 0) {
        return false;
      }
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mLock(cameraMut);
      if (priority < currentPriority) {
        if (mUnlockCameraHandler) {
          mUnlockCameraHandler();
        }
      }
      // ...
```

when using the `UnlockCameraHandler`

```
  void unlock_handler() { camera->unlock(); }
```

Using a `std::recursive_mutex` would fix at least that problem, but there are others.

Particularly, when a low-priority thread has the lock, it can be silently replaced by a lock granted to a higher-priority thread - and the low-priority thread will never know. It will presumably keep using the "protected" device, because nobody told it not to. This design seems unlikely to protect the device the way you want.

Comment: What would you suggest to use instead to automatically signal a low-priority thread that it should unlock the resource before a higher-priority thread can access it?

Comment: I wouldn't, to be honest - handling pre-emption well is difficult. If you must do it, it will be easier to do by integrating the synchronization into some wrapper around the device, so the device access call can check every time whether the calling thread is still permitted.